# delegate the rendering of editable cells to your new EditableCell component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a project for class where we must create a table of grades using react components in java script

I have successfully created the table initially  using the following code

```
export default class GradesTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const gradesTable = this.renderTable(); //must have key
    
    return [
      <h2 key="name">{this.props.courseGrades.courseInfo.name}</h2>,
      <Errors key="err" errors={this.props.errors}/>,
      <table className="grades" key="gradeTable">{gradesTable}</table>
    ];
  }

  renderTable() {
    //sorting statGrades
    let sortedGrades = [];
    sortedGrades = Array.from(this.props.courseGrades.statGrades).sort(cmpEmailIdFn);
    let colId = this.props.courseGrades.sortedColIds;
        
        //array to hold header data
        let header = [];
        //array to hold row data
        let rowData = [];
        //array to hold all rows
        let row = [];
        //initalize header row and push to row array
        for(let i = 0; i < colId.length; i++){
            header.push(<th key={colId[i]}>{colId[i]}</th>);
        }
        row.push(<tr key="header">{header}</tr>);
        
        let areEditable = new Set([1,2,3]);
        areEditable.clear();
        
        //loop through data and construct the row data pushing each row to the row array
        for(let i = 0; i < sortedGrades.length; i++){
            rowData = [];
            for(let j = 0; j < colId.length; j++){
            //if cell is editable insert an input element else insert static data
                if(j >= 3 && j <= 17 && sortedGrades[i][colId[0]] === "" && this.props.isEditable){
                    areEditable.add(sortedGrades[i][colId[j]]);
                    if(sortedGrades[i][colId[j]] === ""){
                        rowData.push(<td key={colId[j]}><input value={sortedGrades[i][colId[j]]} onChange={this.props.onChange}></input></td>));
                    }else{
                        rowData.push(<td key={colId[j]}><input value={sortedGrades[i][colId[j]]} onChange={this.props.onChange}></input></td>);
                    }
                } else{
                        if(sortedGrades[i][colId[j]] === ""){
                            rowData.push(<td key={colId[j]}></td>);
                        }else{
                            rowData.push(<td key={colId[j]}>{sortedGrades[i][colId[j]]}</td>);
                        }
                    }   
            }
            if(sortedGrades[i][colId[1]] != "" && sortedGrades[i][colId[0]] == ""){
                row.push(<tr key={sortedGrades[i][colId[1]]}>{rowData}</tr>);
            }
            else {
            row.push(<tr key={sortedGrades[i][colId[0]]}>{rowData}</tr>);
            }
        }
        //push the row array to a tbody array and return tbody
        let tbody = [];
        tbody.push(<tbody key="tbody">{row}</tbody>);
        return tbody;
  }

}
```

The next step in the development of this table is to create a seperate stateful component that will handle attempts to update the table. I haven't been able to figure out how to delegate the logic in the table to the seperate component. More specifically im unsure where to call the EditableCell component in the creation of the table elements so that the seperate component will handle them on change

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        val: this.props.val
    };
  }

  
  render(){
    let val = this.props;
    return [
            <input 
                value={this.props.val}
                onChange={this.props.onChange(emailId, colId, this.state.val)}
                >
                </input>
            
    ];
  }
}
```

THis is what the second component looks like. How can the management of the input change get delegated to this seperate component

Answer (score 1):

State should live higher up the tree than the components that use it. So if you need to create a separate component that holds the state, that component should contain GradesTable. The containing component, call it GradesContainer can have state, and can pass a function to GradesTable to set the state.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways depending on which layer the two components belong to.

If the table and the input are close to each other in the hierarchy, you may do it in the following way.

```
// Parent.js
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };
  }

  handleInputChange(emailId, colId, value) {
    // also do something about the emailId and ColId
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Table value={this.state.value} />
        <Input value={this.state.value} onChange={handleInputChange} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

```
// Input.js
class Input extends Component {
  handleChange(event) {
    // pass the emailId and ColId to the function
    this.props.handleInputChange(emailId, colId, event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        value={this.props.value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Yet, if they are far away from each other, then you should consider using a state management library like [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) or [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html). What they do is basically create global "store(s)" and allows you to save the state globally so that all components can have access to them at any layer (do not abuse it, if you can handle it with local state, use local state instead).